# Android device not listed in adb devices

Tags: android, debian, usb, adb, fastboot

I have this super cheap [JAY-tech Tablet PC PA7807-8](http://shop.jaytech.de/index.php?a=120) (FYI not *exactly* the linked model) and no matter what I do I couldn't get it recognized by adb/fastboot, meaning it doesn't appear in `adb devices` or `fastboot devices` at all.  It has Android 4.4.2 installed (which can't be updated).  I'm using adb 1.0.31 on an up to date Debian 8.  I have:

- enabled 'Developer options' and therein 'USB debugging'; thereafter the device displays the "USB debugging connected" notification when the cable is in,
- tried all connection types like MTP, PTP, and "USB large storage",
- checked the `idVendor` attribute of the USB device (it's `1f3a`) and added the line `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1f3a", MODE="0666", OWNER="taylan"` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules` after which I rebooted Debian,
- created `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` and added the line `0x1f3a`,
- restarted the adb server, rebooted/unplugged/replugged the device,
- tried running adb kill-server/start-server/devices as root.

Am I missing any possibilities? My Nexus 5 works just fine with adb. **Are there Android devices that flat out don't support adb?**

Edit: by the way, when I set the connection mode to "USB large storage", `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` pop up but neither can be mounted (says "no medium found on sdx" when trying to mount directly, and `sdb1` and such don't pop up); when I set it to MTP, `jmtpfs` still says it couldn't find any MTP devices.

Comment: Windows recognizes it? I mean, do you see it in Windows explorer?

Comment: Please read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html Some parts of it are outdated  - adb is 64bit now and adb_usb.ini whitelist is no longer used. But the rest is still valid. Start with updating your adb version. 1.0.31 is ancient

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo I don't have a Windows machine available. I'll edit the question to add some information related to data transfer though (in a GNU/Linux specific way), in case it helps anyone...

Comment: How about posting your question here http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your Nexus works with ADB the problem is with your JAY-Tech.**
I've learned the hard way that there are lots of devices that flat-out won't work with ADB.
Nexus devices are the only sure bet.